# Splashscreen doesn't show up in taskbar when starting from eclipse

Tags: eclipse, splash-screen

I have an application with splashscreen for it while it is loading. It works perfectly fine(splashscreen shows up in my taskbar while app is loading) when I start my app from compiled jar file.
 But when I start my application from eclipse IDE to debug it, there is no taskbar icon for my application while splashscreen is shown.
 I'm using eclipse 4.4 and SWT library to create splashscreen. My OS is Win 8. 
Thanks.

Comment: Before eclipse IDE which IDE you was using and what is build version of your app.?

Comment: I haven't used any IDE besides Eclipse.

Comment: can you post code where you are getting problem..?

Comment: I don't think this is code related problem. Splashscreen code is just any other splashscreen out there. That's a Eclipse related problem. And there is way to fix it, but eclipse site have gon a long way from there and i can't find it there anymore.